# Does using Fp16 in deeplearning have adverse effect on the end result?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I see tensorflow offers the use of `fp16` in training and testing, is it safe to use it or will it have an adverse effect on the final result?

Comment: You may need to retune hyper parameters

Comment: let me get this straight!, do you mean if I tune my params in fp32 and lets say achieve 98% accuracy, will be forced to retune all params when switched to fp16 and start training from scratch!?

Comment: you need to retune if you want to start training from fp16, if you just convert fp32 to bloat16, then you should be fine

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Also check out this article: https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/. If I remember correctly, the different between float32 and a 8bits quantized model is very tiny.

Comment: @chaiy: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will affect the output while training, because of the extra math precision that float32 provides, but after training you can 'quantize' the operations in your network to float16 to have faster performances if your hardware supports the float16 natively. If the hardware does not support such operation you might likely have a slow down in terms of performances.

Answer (score 2):

according to wikipedia data,the half precision float point performance on nvidia cards is even worse than using double, and i am wondoring performance reports to confirm that idea(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1300,see the bottom of the page, a 10% performance was reported).
hence we can conclude that using fp16 is centered on the video ram issue(or,scale of model),training was to be carried out normally, 
it is OK to use lower precision, binary connection was also investigated. fit would be archived anyway
In contrast, the amd cards can offer astonishing fp16 performance while software support is rare. e.g. theano and the libgpuarray backgroud on openCL.though...people use fp32 to calculate

Comment: Thanks. Yes the new pascal architecture fp16 performance is worse than Maxwell's . and this was deliberately done by nvidia. but I have'nt seen any report on AMDs. do you have any to back your claim on AMD fp16 performance?

Comment: wikipedia, the radeon 400 GPU page. and it seems no reference on that page supports the data in the table